# Не работает алгоритм по подсчету пешек на шахматной доске

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста. У меня задача посчитать количество пешек в безопасной позиции. Я создал виртуальную шахматную доску. У меня есть наборы позиций пешек, из 4 наборов не работает последний, это связано с тем, что я, фактически убрал самый нижний ряд из расчетов, т.к. физически, пешки не могут находиться на самом нижнем ряду. Но проблема, в том, что в одном из проверочных сетов, пешки располагаются по главной диагонали. И при использовании последнего сета, я не могу посчитать 1 пешку на нижнем ряду.
Может быть есть решение для подсчета пешек и с нижним рядом, не исключая его?
s = "b4", "d4", "f4", "c3", "e3", "g5", "d2"  - ок

x = "b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4", "g4", "e5" - ок

f = "a1","b2","c3","d4","e5","f6","g7","h8" - ок  ( при исключении нижнего ряда)
last = "a8","b7","c6","d5","e4","f3","g2","h1" - неправильный результат.

````
for i in range(8, 0, -1):
for j in 'abcdefgh':
       chess.append(j + str(i))

y = 0
indexes = [i for i in last if chess.index(i) < 55]
for i in indexes:
   if chess[chess.index(i) + 7] in last or chess[chess.index(i) + 9] in last:
        y += 1

print(y) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

У вас само условие противоречиво. Написано: "пешки не могут находиться на самом нижнем ряду. Но проблема, в том, что в одном из проверочных сетов, пешки располагаются по главной диагонали." -т.е. они находятся. Соответственно, не надо исключать нижний ряд.

Comment: Да именно так, благодарю Вас.

Comment: хорошо, тогда ответ помечают +1 (треугольник вверх), вроде тут. Если так - отметьте, пожалуйста:)

Comment: Сергей, вы знаете, не получается :) Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются

Comment: Странно. Я, например, ваш вопрос сейчас так отметил - все работает (свой вопрос или ответ, конечно, не пометить, а вот чужой ответ под своим вопросом - и треугольник нажимается, и зеленая галочка под ним (что вопрос отвечен)).